# R localização reta de x em y

Tags: r

Estou com essa dúvida, mas sinceramente não sei se a solução realmente existe no R.

Tenho um gráfico x/y, e quero traçar duas retas, (1) do eixo x até o dado e outra (2) do eixo y até a dado. A reta 1, eu tenho o valor dela, seria o tercil do meu eixo. A questão é, como encontrar o exato ponto em que a reta cruza no dado e plotar seguindo para o eixo y?

Eu já tentei, pela posição do eixo x, usar a mesma posição para y. Isso até funciona para alguns dados, mas não todos (pois os valores nem sempre são correspondentes).

Segue abaixo meu exemplo,

```
x<-seq(1,30)

dado<-c(0.96523390,0.93066061,0.89634466,0.86213300,0.82769878, 
  0.79311455,0.75831596,0.72311471,0.68800759,0.65245482,0.61700818,
  0.58163643,0.51021060,0.47393336,0.43788203,0.40203755,0.36614804,
  0.33059801,0.29408090,0.25820874,0.22265365,0.18803136,0.15444785,
  0.11931985,0.08411248,0.05098459,0.01957279,0.01358753,0.01257345,
  0.00986485)

plot(x,dado,type="l")

tercil<-quantile(x,probs=1/3)
abline(v=tercil,col="red",lwd=2)
```

### Edição após duas tentativas de reposta

Eu testei das duas formas e não consegui. Na primeira sugestão, os resultados de "dado[ceiling(tercil)]+.01" retornam NA. E na segunda, as curvas se cruzam em pontos diferentes das minhas retas. Como acima só apresentei um exemplo (até achando que não existiria algo como solução), escrevo novamente como resposta, mas dessa vez apresentando meus dados reais.

Os dados sairam de uma análise que eu fiz, então eles se relacionam entre eles. Por isso, a ideia é calcular o tercil de um dos dados, mas plotar até a interseção com o outro lado. Vou escrever abaixo tudo o que fiz, talvez seja melhor compreendido.

```
     ob<-c(77.89824, 170.36929, 90.88129, 141.22368, 174.07871, 106.51393, 94.32576,
85.31712, 78.95808, 222.30143, 115.25760, 85.84704, 165.33504, 72.06912,
38.94912, 90.88129, 167.18976, 125.85600, 141.22367, 104.65922, 131.95009, 81.07777,
64.12032,130.36032, 89.29152, 65.97504, 40.27392, 64.38529, 113.40288)
```

A partir do meu ob, eu fiz algumas análises, usei também o modelo de Cox e gerei as variáveis abaixo.

```
     tm<-c(38.94912, 40.27392, 64.12032, 64.38529, 65.97504, 72.06912, 77.89824, 78.95808, 
81.07777, 85.31712, 85.84704, 89.29152, 90.88129, 94.32576, 104.65922, 106.51393, 
113.40288, 115.25760, 125.85600, 130.36032, 131.95009, 141.22367, 141.22368, 165.33504,
167.18976, 170.36929, 174.07871)    

    bs<-c(0.96523390, 0.93066061, 0.89634466, 0.86213300, 0.82769878, 0.79311455,
0.75831596, 0.72311471, 0.68800759, 0.65245482, 0.61700818, 0.58163643, 0.51021060,
0.47393336, 0.43788203, 0.40203755, 0.36614804, 0.33059801, 0.29408090, 0.25820874,
0.22265365, 0.18803136, 0.15444785, 0.11931985, 0.08411248, 0.05098459, 0.01957279)

    prc<-c(0.956974397, 0.914559074, 0.872836231, 0.831624652, 0.790544222,
0.749700646, 0.709038330, 0.668364230, 0.628275180, 0.588180704, 0.548730882,
0.509909531, 0.433282681, 0.395329802, 0.358306283, 0.322222487, 0.286868665,
0.252670119, 0.218461386, 0.185847964, 0.154593177, 0.125303855, 0.098121311,
0.071199383, 0.046104574, 0.024746731, 0.007529233)

plot(tm,bs,type="l",col="red")
lines(tm,prc,col="black")
```

Nesse ponto, eu fiz o tercil da minha variável base "ob", afim de que pudesse traçar as retas.

```
tinf<-quantile(ob,prob=1/3)
tsup<-quantile(ob,prob=2/3)
```

A ideia com o idxinf, é encontrar algum valor 'igual ou próximo (+/-5)' para poder usar. Caso encontre mais de um valor dentro desse range, ele faz a média entre eles.

```
idxinf<-which(tm>=(tinf-5) & tm<=(tinf+5))
infgrafico<-mean(prc[idxinf])
idxsup<-which(tm>=(tsup-5) & tm<=(tsup+5))
supgrafico<-mean(prc[idxsup])

segments(tinf,0.03, tinf,infgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(min(tm),infgrafico, tinf,infgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
text(tinf,cex=1,y=0,col="black",font=2,"T1")
segments(tsup,0.03, tsup,supgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(min(tm),supgrafico, tsup,supgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
text(tsup,cex=1,y=0,col="black",font=2,"T2")
```

Mas é isso, as vezes os valores não são correspondentes e não se encontram, fazendo com que as retas não se cruzem no valor do dado. 
E sim, eu precisaria de algo mais automatizado possível, pois tenho que salvar esses valores em uma tabela, e não conseguiria fazer na mão/tentativa e erro, um por um.

Answer (score 5):

Eu não vejo uma solução automatizada para isso por dois motivos.

1. Tu não tem (ou ao menos não forneceu) uma função que relacione `x` e `dado`. Desta forma, é impossível calcular `dado` a partir de `x`. Talvez esta função nem exista, pois estes dados podem ser experimentais.
2. `x` está definido nos inteiros entre 1 e 30, mas `quantile(x,probs=1/3)` é igual a `10.66667`, o que inviabiliza relacionar os `x` originais com a observação correspondente em dados.

Veja que ao tentar fazer o gráfico pedido, isto vai implicar que as retas vermelhas não vão tocar a curva preta, justamente por causa destes problemas de arredondamento:

```
x<-seq(1,30)

dado<-c(0.96523390,0.93066061,0.89634466,0.86213300,0.82769878,
        0.79311455,0.75831596,0.72311471,0.68800759,0.65245482,
        0.61700818,0.58163643,0.51021060,0.47393336,0.43788203,
        0.40203755,0.36614804,0.33059801,0.29408090,0.25820874,
        0.22265365,0.18803136,0.15444785,0.11931985,0.08411248,
        0.05098459,0.01957279,0.01358753,0.01257345,0.00986485)

plot(x,dado,type="l")

tercil<-quantile(x,probs=1/3)

segments(tercil, -1, tercil, dado[ceiling(tercil)], col = "red")
segments(-1, dado[ceiling(tercil)], tercil, dado[ceiling(tercil)], col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que dá pra fazer é, através de tentativa e erro, estimar o quanto falta para as retas vermelhas encontrarem a preta e adicionar isso ao código. Eu fiz uns testes aqui e fiquei satisfeito com o resultado:

```
segments(tercil, -1, tercil, dado[ceiling(tercil)]+.01, col = "red")
segments(-1, dado[ceiling(tercil)]+0.01, tercil, dado[ceiling(tercil)]+.01, col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema desta solução é que ela não é universal. Caso outro gráfico similar tenha que ser construído, vai ser necessário utilizar tentativa e erro novamente, a não ser que os itens 1 ou 2 das minhas observações acima sejam alterados ou caso em vez de usar o tercil, seja usado um outro valor para `x` que tenha correspondente em `dados`, como 11, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira é ajustar um modelo linear, uma vez que o gráfico de `(x, dado)` é quase uma reta.

Este valor é comum aos dois gráficos abaixo.

```
tercil <- quantile(x, probs = 1/3)
```

Agora, vendo o gráfico só de `x` e `dado` vê-se que não é uma reta perfeita mas quase. Assim, vou primeiro ajustar um modelo com os dados completos. O valor de `y` correspondente a `tercil` será calculado como o valor de predição do modelo.

```
plot(x, dado, type = "l", main = "Primeiro modelo: dados completos")
abline(v = tercil, col = "red", lwd = 2)

fit <- lm(dado ~ x, data = data.frame(x, dado))
hpred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = tercil))
abline(h = hpred, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A reta horizontal não passa na intersecção da reta vertical com o gráfico dos dados. Então, vou ajustar o modelo a dados truncados, com `x < 11`.

```
plot(x, dado, type = "l", main = "Segundo modelo: dados truncados")
abline(v = tercil, col = "red", lwd = 2)

fit2 <- lm(dado ~ x, data = subset(data.frame(x, dado), x < 11))
hpred2 <- predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(x = tercil))
abline(h = hpred2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edição.**

Ainda outro método, desta vez com splines.

```
interpolar <- function(x, y, quantil = (1:2)/3, 
                       col = "red", col_points = "black", 
                       col_spline = "green", plot = TRUE, ...)
{
    f <- splinefun(x, y, method = "monoH.FC")
    qq <- quantile(x, quantil)
    y_qq <- f(qq)
    N <- length(x)*10
    X1 <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = N)
    if(plot){
        plot(x, y, type = "p", pch = 20, col = col_points, ...)
        lines(X1, f(X1), col = col_spline, lty = "dashed")
        abline(v = qq, col = col)
        abline(h = y_qq, col = col)
    }
    res <- list(horiz = y_qq, vert = qq)
    invisible(res)
}

result <- interpolar(x, y, main = "Interpolação com splines")
result
#$horiz
#33.33333% 66.66667% 
#0.6126024 0.2309008 
#
#$vert
#33.33333% 66.66667% 
#  83.9040  118.7904
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]